# Uncaught reference error: xy not defined but working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have something like this in which the value gets updated (`$('#'+name+userid).val(value);`), but the `userid` variable cannot be found. If I define a new `userid` variable as a.attr('userid'), the value does not get updated. Why is this working then?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../modify_users_admin.inc.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        value: a.attr('value'),
        name: a.attr('name'),
        userid: a.attr('userid')

        },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#'+name+userid).val(value);
        if (data) {
            console.log('s');
            alert(data);

        } else {
            $('#notice').text('Updated');
            $('#notice').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: name and userid are not variables but key of object data passed as request param which is not the same as object returned by the request.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle or post some more of your code, showing what `a` is and how you are using the ajax?

Comment: a is an input field, but it's irrelevant now

Comment: _"Why is this working then?"_ - I don't see how it could be when the line `$('#'+name+userid).val(value);` has three different variables that are not mentioned anywhere else in the code shown - are `name` and/or `userid` and/or `value` defined elsewhere in your code? What is the exact error message? Is it really "xy not defined", or does it reference the variables that you actually show in your code above?

Comment: `uncaught referenceError: userid not defined`
maybe Chrome tried to fix it on its own?? it shouldn't work but it does; and it's strange since with proper variable declaration it stops working

Comment: Do show the rest of your code. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `userid` and `name` in a variables and then use them

```
function foo(a) {

    var userid = a.attr('userid');
    var name = a.attr('name');

    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: {
            ...
            name: name,
            userid: userid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#'+name+userid).val(value);
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

and call function `foo`

Comment: that's the way I tried and this way the value itself does not get updated

Comment: without variable declaration it gets updated but chrome js debug throws an error (in title) every time